# How to ignore UnknownElements on deserialization (XmlSerializer) by using a WCF SoapClient?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, xml-serialization

I have a C#-Project where I added a WCF Service References via a WSDL-File. Because I don't want to use the  "DataContractSerializer", I changed the "Reference.svcmap" and set the Serializer to "XmlSerializer". At this Point all works perfectly.

Now to the Problem. The Service is not my Service and it can be, that the programmer of the service adds properties to the result classes and I can't update my reference at the same time.  So it can be, that my imported WSDL is out of date. In this case the result after deserialization is not correct.

For example the result has the properties "Name", "Street" and "Town". If the service now returns...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <TestResult xmlns="http://test.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Tim</Name>
  <Street>Samplestreet</Street>
  <Town>Sampletown</Town>
</TestResult>
```

my result has the values:

Name=Tim
 
Street=Samplestreet
 
Town=Sampletown

If the service programmer now adds the property "Fullname" between "Name" and "Street" and my WSDL-import is out of date, the result will become incorrect. The service returns...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <TestResult xmlns="http://test.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Tim</Name>
  <FullName>Tim Brown</FullName>
  <Street>Samplestreet</Street>
  <Town>Sampletown</Town>
</TestResult>
```

but after deserializition my result has the values :

Name=Tim
Street=null
Town=null

It looks like the XmlSerialzier of WCF stops the deserializition at the point it founds a UnknownElement without an exception.

The question, is there a setting, a way to configure the service reference, SoapClient  or Serializier to ignore the UnknownElement and continue with the deserializition like a standard XmlSerialzier how returns all the values it knows?

Or is there a way to use a own Serialzier on client side in a WCF SoapClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the Answer of "Legart" I looked inside the generated file "**Reference.cs**" and find out, why I got a wrong deserialization result, when the Service sends me a result with a new element that is unknown for my service reference.

The Problem is that in the generated Reference file the "**XmlElementArributes**" has a parameter named "**Order**". If the Service sent me now a new, unknown element it could be, that this element changes the order of the elements and then the deserialisation will return a wrong result.

My current solution is to remove all the "Order"-Parameters in the Attributes. Then the changed order and added elements in the Server result has no effect to the deserialization. It’s like the new, unknown elements will be ignored.

It’s not the best solution because I must edit a generated file, but at the moment it works for me.

If you know a better way, please write a comment.

Comment: Yes, editing reference.cs is not the best way. Do you have order attributes on server side?

Comment: I don't know, because I'm not the programmer on server side. That's why I searched a way, that my program on client side don't get big problems, if there are small changes on server side. For example some changes, that change the element order. At the moment my solution works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add additional property to you class TestResult and mark it with XmlAnyElement:

```
[XmlAnyElement]
public XmlElement[] AllElements;
```

[XmlAnyElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx)

For DataContract, DataMember style you can implement IExtensibleDataObject interface:

[IExtensibleDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it was not the solution of my problem, but it helped me to find the real problem why I become a wrong serialization result. 
More Information, see my Answer.